# Pull knexnest call out to file of its own to prevent duplication

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm using knexnest as follows:

```
const customerProducts = knex.select([
  'CustomerProduct.id AS _id',
  'CustomerProduct.price AS _price',
  'CustomerProduct.active AS _active',
  'CustomerProduct.customer_id AS _customerId',
  'CustomerProduct.product_id AS _productId',
  'customer.id AS _customer_id',
  'customer.name AS _customer_name',
])
  .from('customer_products AS CustomerProduct')
  .innerJoin(
    'customers AS customer',
    'CustomerProduct.customer_id',
    'customer.id',
  )
  .where(whereClause);

const result = knexnest(customerProducts).then(data => data);
  return result;
```

I'll likely be creating several other queries with which I'll then use knexnest to create a nested model. Is there a way that I can pull `knexnest(customerProducts).then(data => data);` out to a different file so that I could just call it rather than adding that line with every query and also having to import knexnest into every file?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're trying to accomplish, the simplest way would be to export a function that returns the promise generated by `knexnest`. Then, import that function in the main file and call it. You can either use async/await syntactic sugar or a `.then`. It's important that you use one knex connection object throughout your application to leverage knex's connection pool. Therefore, we must pass it into your function so the other file can access the established connection object.

#### File 1

```
const Knex = require('knex');

// import the function getCustomerProducts using destructuring 
const { getCustomerProducts } = require('<File 2's Path>');

// initialize knex & set up knex database connection
const knex = Knex({
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
});

// pseudo-code - note: await can only be called within an async function
// pass knex connection object into function to leverage knex's connection pooling
const products = await getCustomerProducts(knex);
```

#### File 2

```
const knexnest = require('knexnest');

const getCustomerProducts = knex => {

  const customerProducts = knex.select([
      'CustomerProduct.id AS _id',
      'CustomerProduct.price AS _price',
      'CustomerProduct.active AS _active',
      'CustomerProduct.customer_id AS _customerId',
      'CustomerProduct.product_id AS _productId',
      'customer.id AS _customer_id',
      'customer.name AS _customer_name',
    ])
    .from('customer_products AS CustomerProduct')
    .innerJoin(
      'customers AS customer',
      'CustomerProduct.customer_id',
      'customer.id',
    )
    .where(whereClause);

  return knexnest(customerProducts);
};

// named export of the function getCustomerProducts
module.exports.getCustomerProducts = getCustomerProducts;
```